# How to predict t+2 until t+5 when use multivariate time series?

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis

I want to make stock price predictions for the next 5 days. For example, to predict the closing price on the t+1, I will use the closing price, the lowest price, and the highest price on the t, (t-1) to (t-10). This is allowed right and does not include data leakage? What I'm confused about is how to make predictions on t+2 to t+5? I read that to predict t+2 and so on, we use the predicted data from the previous day. However, in this case, I only predict the closing price. For example, to predict t+2 I will use the predicted closing price at t+1, but what about the data for the lowest price and the highest price at t+1? Is the multivariate time series unable to make predictions for t+2 and so on? and do I have to use multistep multivariate time series in my case?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question really depends on the model you are using to make predictions. For example if you have a simple AR(1) your expected prediction for 2 periods ahead is:

AR(1) model is
$
y_t = a_0 + a_1 * y_{t-1} + v_t
$

Then prediction 2 periods ahead is:

$
\\E_t(y_{t+2}) = E_t(a_0 + a_1 * y_{t+1} + v_t)  \\
E_t(y_{t+2}) = a_0+ a_1 * E_t(y_{t+1}) \\
$

Therefore you need to put in your prediction for $y_{t+1}$ to find the t+2 solution. If your model is different, this might not be necessary.

As a side note, you should take a close look at variance and confidence interval of your estimates and look for unit root tests to check for stationarity. I have found it difficult to find these results in stock market data, specially for daily data. Day to day trading has much higher volatility, information shocks etc. and these things may create too much noise in your data so that the model may underperform.

Comment: Welcome to CV, Tomas!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my question is a multivariate time series that has 3 independent variables to predict the closing price. Your answer is only for univariate time series, right?